# DockerでOracle Databaseをインストールしようとすると起こるエラーについて

Tags: docker, oracle

環境
MacBook Pro M2 16GB

`./buildContainerImage.sh -v 19.3.0 -e -I` コマンドを使用して、Oracle Database 19.3.0をインストールしようとしたのですが、画像のようにエラーが発生し、インストールできません。解決方法をどなたかご教授していただきたいです。

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c \"$ORACLE_BASE\"/oraInventory/orainstRoot.sh &&     \"$ORACLE_HOME\"/root.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

`$ORACLE_BASE` をくくる前後のダブルクォートが余計な気がします。

修正例:

```
RUN $ORACLE_BASE/oraInventory/orainstRoot.sh && ¥ 
$ORACLE_HOME/root.sh
```

Comment: そのダブルクォーテーションを取るにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？